# Why am i getting output as null when i try to print cover array?

Tags: java, json, list, gson

I am using GSON to parse a JSON file but I am getting `null` as output when I print the elements inside cover array. 
I need the `coverName`, `coverID` and `benefitsIncluded`.

I am sure that I am doing something silly somewhere. Please take a look at the relevant files.

**request.json**

```
{
"email": "someone@example.com",
"firstName": "someone",
"lastname": "",
"policyNumber": "PHD121213213123Q1",
"premiumAmount": "200.00",
"premiumFrequency": "Monthly",
"cover": [{
        "coverName": "Child Critical Illness",
        "coverID": 10000,
        "benefitsIncluded": [
            "Lump sum payment",
            "No waiting period",
            "Unlimited claim limit per policy owner"
        ]
    },
    {
        "coverName": "Life Coverage",
        "coverID": 10001,
        "benefitsIncluded": [
            "Lump sum benefit should the life insured pass away",
            "Max of 1 Mn per Home Loan",
            "Max 2 Mn per policy Owner",
            "Up to $50k per account for each Credit Card and Personal Loan"
        ]
    },
    {
        "coverName": "Critical Illness",
        "coverID": 10002,
        "benefitsIncluded": [
            "lump sum payment of 12 monthly disability payment",
            "max of 120K per home loan account",
            "max of 50K per credit card and personal loan "
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**Insured.java**

```
public class Insured {
private String email;
private String firstName;
private String lastname;
private String policyNumber;
private String applicationPageLink;
private String premiumAmount;
private String premiumFrequency;
private List<Cover> cover;
//Getters and Setters
```

**Cover.java**

```
public class Cover {
    private String coverName;
    private String coverId;
    private List<String> Benefits;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

**Main method**

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException {

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("json file path");
    BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    Insured insured = new Gson().fromJson(buffer, Insured.class);

    for (Cover cover : insured.getCover()) {
        System.out.println(cover.getBenefits());
        System.out.println(cover.getCoverId());
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `Cover` class, change the field name from `Benefits` to `benefitsIncluded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting `null` is that GSON is not able to match the fields from your `Cover` object with the ones from the JSON because property names are different (in particular, you have `coverId` vs `coverID` and `Benefits` vs `benefitsIncluded`).

To solve the issue you have 2 alternatives:

1. Rename your Java fields so that they exactly match the ones in the JSON, like this:

   ```
   class Cover {
       private String coverName;
       private String coverID;
       private List<String> benefitsIncluded;

       //Getters and Setters
       ...
   }
   ```

   However, this solution is not very elegant because it might make you not follow Java naming conventions.
2. Add a [`@SerializedName("xxx")`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation for each field with a different name, where `xxx` is the name of the property in the JSON, like this:

   ```
   class Cover {
       private String coverName;
       @SerializedName("coverID")
       private String coverId;
       @SerializedName("benefitsIncluded")
       private List<String> benefits;

       //Getters and Setters
       ....
   }
   ```

   Note that with this solution you're **not** forced to add a `@SerializedName` annotation for each field, but only for the fields having a different name between Java and JSON.

In both cases you'll end up with the following output:

```
[Lump sum payment, No waiting period, Unlimited claim limit per policy owner]
10000
[Lump sum benefit should the life insured pass away, Max of 1 Mn per Home Loan, Max 2 Mn per policy Owner, Up to $50k per account for each Credit Card and Personal Loan]
10001
[lump sum payment of 12 monthly disability payment, max of 120K per home loan account, max of 50K per credit card and personal loan ]
10002
```